# RetNet Paper Multi Scale Retention dimemsion question

Tags: deep-learning, transformer, mathematics

From the paper:
https://arxiv.org/pdf/2307.08621.pdf
[image: From the paper]

But since X is of size n by $d_{model}$. [image][image: Retention]

How can we compute $XW_Q$? Since the row length of X which is $d_{model}$ is not the same as the column length of $W_Q$ which is $d$.